# Can I connect to any AirPlay device from the WatchOS 3 Control Center?

Tags: audio, airplay, apple-watch, watchos

In WatchOS 3, there is an AirPlay button at the very bottom of the control center.

[image]

When I press it, the only option I see is *Apple Watch*.

[image]

But on my iPhone, I'm playing audio from SoundCloud. I'm there able to assign the audio playback to AirPlay devices:

[image]

As noted in the image, I'm not using a real AirPlay device but a virtual one, via Airfoil playing on my Mac. But it should still behave like a real AirPlay device.

So, is this new button in the WatchOS 3 control center just for "AirPods" and the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Apple Watch, go to the Settings app, go to Bluetooth, and pair each of the devices you want to use.

The Apple Watch is connecting directly to the device by Bluetooth, not using your iPhone's connection.

Comment: Okay, that kind of makes sense I guess – except that it's the iPhone playing the audio and not the Watch, so why would the watch connect directly to an Bluetooth device instead of relaying the AirPlay/Bluetooth options of the iPhone? Not that I'm doubting you, it's an open question. However, I'm going to take you at your word here because it seems plausible (unfortunately I can't verify the answer since I don't have any physical bluetooth devices to connect to).